# AngularJS, using ng-repeat for both rows and columns on a table

Tags: angularjs, html-table, salesforce

So it's pretty easy to make a table that repeats set values for columns.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in list">
    <td>{{ x.Id }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Status__c }}</td>
</tr>
```

But say I didn't know exactly what columns were going to show on the table.  One object might have the third column be "Status__c", but another object might have the third column be "Type__c".

passing a list of objects (as "list") and the names of the fields (as "fields"), this is the closest I've gotten.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in list">
    <td ng-repeat="f in fields">{{ x.f }} </td>
</tr>
```

changing "{{ x.f }}" to "{{ x }}" shows the whole json string for the object. Changing it to "{{ f }}" shows the field name (i.e. "Type__c") correctly.

"{{ x.f }}" doesn't work.  Neither does "{{ x }}.{{ f }}" or "{{ x.{{ f }} }}".

Comment: Did you try {{x[f]}}

Answer (score 0):

I tested in plunker, and {{ x[f] }} should work for you.